# How to run a docker container from within java

Tags: java, macos, docker, docker-java

I want to run the following command from within a Java Eclipse Project:

```
docker container run -p 4000:5000 virtuprint:vp
```

where `virtuprint:vp` is an image.
I installed the docker-java api from here https://github.com/docker-java/docker-java using all its dependencies via maven.
I am using MacOS, I guess that's causing my trouble.

I already read the docs and wikis, and just did some test code to see if it's running (and of course it's not.)

```java
DockerClient dockerClient = DockerClientBuilder.getInstance().build();

        List<Container> containers = dockerClient.listContainersCmd().exec();

        for(Container c: containers) {
            System.out.println(c.getId());
        }
```

So I just want to print the container-ID in short term. Long term I want to run multiple docker containers on demand from within my java application.
But if I run the code I get:

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.newsclub.net.unix.NativeUnixSocket

I guess it's because he is trying to find unix sockets on places they aren't, but I neither know where they are nor how to tell him where to find them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Played with the dependencies, downgraded to version 3.0.14 and sticked closely to this guide:
https://www.baeldung.com/docker-java-api

don't know why but now it works.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same issue, but the issue got resolved when I switched to JAVA 8.
There is an issue with JAVA11 and higher versions.

[JAVA 11 and Docker-java issue](https://github.com/bmuschko/gradle-docker-plugin/issues/874)